# Does Terry Pratchett refer to Napier's Bones for Logarithms here?

Tags: soft-question, logarithms

[Terry Pratchett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett) is brilliant, and I get most of the references, but there [is one](https://www.npr.org/books/titles/295160774/raising-steam) I'm struggling with in [Raising Steam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_Steam) on p13:

> Dick was braced for stiff objections, but he hadn't reckoned on tears—so many tears—and as he tried to console her he added, "You, Mother, and Uncle Flavius got me an education, you got me the knowing of the numbers, including the arithmetic and weird stuff dreamed up by the philosophers in Ephebe where even camels can do logarithms on their toes. Dad didn't know this stuff. He had the right ideas but he didn't have the?.?.?.?tech-nol-ogy right."

I think this refers to [Napier's Bones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napier%27s_bones), but it doesn't sound quite right.

My question is: **Does Terry Pratchett refer to Napier's Bones for Logarithms here?**

Comment: As that wikipedia page itself says in the second paragraph, Napier's bones don't have anything to do with logarithms.

Comment: I was puzzled by the question marks in the ellipsis until I saw that that's how it appears in the NPR excerpt. The book itself typesets things as "the ... *tech-nol-ogy*." The typo, I suspect, is an artefact of word-processor incompatibility.

Comment: In Terry's book Pyramids, (or Small Gods?) camels were good at advanced mathematics, although people didn't know that.

Comment: @Empy2, that's a helpful reference! A pertinent excerpt from *Pyramids* may help explain the choice of toes for doing logarithms: "Lack of fingers was another big spur to the development of camel intellect. Human mathematical development had always been held back by everyone’s instinctive tendency, when faced with something really complex in the way of triform polynomials or parametric differentials, to count fingers. Camels started from the word go by counting *numbers*" In sum, Pratchett is more likely making an internal, disc-world reference than a reference to Napier. But who knows.

Comment: Then he called us, I mean them, 'Bloody Stupid', 'You Bastard' and 'Evil-Smelling Bugger'  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simpler alternative is to read it as a reference to circus horses which allegedly do simple arithmetic and tap out the answer with their hooves.